# For what values of $p$ is this series absolutely / conditionally convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

For what values of $p$ is this series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^k}{k^p}{logk}$$

```
                 a) absolutely convergent 

                 b) and conditionally convergent?
```

I think that if $p ≤-2$  then it will be absolutely convergent and if $p≤1$   then it will be conditionally convergent.

Please tell me if it's correct or not or give me any hints.

Comment: I have corrected a certain number of incorrect terms. For example "pliz" (SMS language) $\to$ "please".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let let $p=-n$ then

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^k}\frac{logk}{k^n}$$

Therefore the the series

- converges absolutely for $n>1$, that is $p<-1$,
- and it is conditionally convergent for for $n>0$, that is $p<0$.

Comment: thanks a lots,,,gimusi

Comment: You are welcome, please feel free to ask for any other doubt.